# losing capabilities after setuid()

Tags: c, linux, privileges, linux-capabilities

Trying to set `cap_setgid`,`cap_setuid`,`cap_setpcap`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>

int main()
{
    cap_t caps;
    caps = cap_get_proc();
    cap_value_t cap_list[2];

    cap_list[0] = CAP_SETUID;
    cap_list[1] = CAP_SETGID;

    cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_EFFECTIVE, 2, cap_list, CAP_SET);
    cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_INHERITABLE, 2, cap_list, CAP_SET);
    cap_set_proc(caps);
    cap_free(caps);
    setgid(65534);
    setuid(65534);

    cap_get_proc();
    setgid(0);
    setuid(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Execution is going under root user. 
Tracing the program shows this

```
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, NULL) = 0
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, 0}) = 0
capset({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP}) = 0
setgid(65534)                           = 0
setuid(65534)                           = 0
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, NULL) = 0
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {0, 0, CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP}) = 0
setgid(0)                               = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
setuid(0)                               = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Privileges are set but do not work. Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

UPDATE: `prctl` added to code

```
21a22
> prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, 1, 0, 0, 0);
24a26
> cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_EFFECTIVE, 3, cap_list, CAP_SET);
```

so now it is

```
prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, 1, 0, 0, 0);
setgid(65534);
setuid(65534);
cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_EFFECTIVE, 3, cap_list, CAP_SET);
```

Caps were inherited after `setuid`, and caps that were set manually are still there, but it didn't solve the problem

```
setgid(65534)                           = 0
setuid(65534)                           = 0
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, NULL) = 0
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {0, CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP}) = 0
setgid(0)                               = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
setuid(0)                               = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

UPDATE2:
Can't understand it. Ive added 2strs after 1st `setuid`, to check out for caps.

```
printf("cape set %d\n", cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_EFFECTIVE, 3, cap_list, CAP_SET));
printf("%s\n", cap_to_text(cap_get_proc(), NULL));
```

it returned

```
catp set 0
=p cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap+i
```

Effective flag is not set, but cap_set_flag returned 0

Comment: sorry. solved by adding cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_INHERITABLE, 2, cap_list, CAP_SET)

Comment: Post it as an answer and accept it. It's recommended to do it if you solved your own problem. Future programmer will find it easily. Add also an explanation on why it's needed.

Comment: Ok. Wait for someone to help you. Consider my comments only if you solve it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, capability sets are lost across an UID transition; use

```
prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

to retain **permitted** capabilities (`cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_PERMITTED, ...)`).  Note that the **effective** capability set will be reset, but can be re-established.

---

The following works fine for me.

```
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cap_value_t cap_values[] = {CAP_SETUID, CAP_SETGID};
    cap_t caps;

    caps = cap_get_proc();
    cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_PERMITTED, 2, cap_values, CAP_SET);
    cap_set_proc(caps);
    prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    cap_free(caps);

    setgid(65534);
    setuid(65534);

    caps = cap_get_proc();
    cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_EFFECTIVE, 2, cap_values, CAP_SET);
    cap_set_proc(caps);
    cap_free(caps);

    setgid(0);
    setuid(0);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ sudo strace ./a.out
...
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, 0}) = 0
capset({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, 0}) = 0
prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, 1)               = 0
setgid(65534)                           = 0
setuid(65534)                           = 0
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, NULL) = 0
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {0, CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, 0}) = 0
capset({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID, CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_FSETID|CAP_KILL|CAP_SETGID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_RAWIO|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_PACCT|CAP_SYS_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_MKNOD|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL|CAP_SETFCAP, 0}) = 0
setgid(0)                               = 0
setuid(0)                               = 0
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Ive made changes in code after ur post, but the problem is still there. look at question update, pls

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused CAP_PERMITTED set with CAP_INHERITABLE, 
Unless you are using threads/exec , you want to use CAP_PERMITTED.

> Inheritable (formerly known as allowed):
>                 This  set  is  ANDed  with  the thread's inheritable set to determine which inheritable capabilities are enabled in the
>   permitted set of the thread after the execve(2)

As for update2: try printing out `cap_to_text(cap_get_proc())` before/after and also consider what is the difference between `cap_set_flag` and `cap_set_proc`.